# How to print emojis in Jimp - Node Js | Jimp

Tags: javascript, node.js, jimp

I'm building a nodejs app that generates tweets by text and some of the target tweets contain emojis in text or in user name.
But when I try to print those emojis in Jimp, it converts the emoji into "??".
I already tried to use "NotoColorEmoji" and "NotoEmoji-Regular" fonts but they appear as blank squares when I try to convert-em into .fnt files.

This is how the fonts look like when converted:
[Font after converting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOAX2.png)

How can I make Jimp display those emojis in the `print()` function?

Comment: Give this converter a try, maybe it will fix your font [https://github.com/kreativekorp/bitsnpicas](https://github.com/kreativekorp/bitsnpicas). You must import a bitmap font.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.